# Get rotation from camera matrix of format x y z w

Tags: javascript, camera-matrix

I have a 4x4 matrix within JS called world to obj. This matrix I assume from context must be the camera transformations matrix and thus I am trying to extract the rotation from it in radians on x y and z axis.

I have no clue where to start and have tried many things

for context this below image it the camera transformations with no rotation

[image]

This second one is with rotation of 1 radian is applied to each axis. it is important to note that this camera is orbiting as well in this example

[image]

Comment: In case it's worth mentioning, it appears as though all the fields have been alphabetically organized. This is almost certainly a distraction at the very least. The first matrix appears to be an identity matrix, albeit with the wx, wy & wz components holding the translation vector. I mean, everything's zero or one with the exception of the w vector. ;) (neglecting FP rounding errors of course, which give you the tiny little non-zero numbers)

Comment: This thread might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati/3554913